# Add to dictionary type error in C#

Tags: c#

```
        DeductFamily = this.GroupPlanSearcher.GetAvailableDeductFamily(searchParam).ToDictionary().Add("abc", "abc"),
```

Above is my code to add one item ("abc", "abc") to the dictionary generated by ToDictionary(), but I got the following error:

"cannot implicitly convert void to System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary"

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary.Add()` returns `void`.

```
//  Nope.
var x = list.ToDictionary().Add("x", "y");
```

You need to create the dictionary in one statement, and add an item to it in another:

```
DeductFamily = this.GroupPlanSearcher.GetAvailableDeductFamily(searchParam).ToDictionary();

DeductFamily.Add("abc", "abc"),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know this!!

Answer (score 1):

The `Add` operation returns `void`, you should be doing that on the next line after assigning `Dictionary` to your variable.

```
DeductFamily = this.GroupPlanSearcher.GetAvailableDeductFamily(searchParam).ToDictionary();

DeductFamily.Add("abc", "abc");
```